# Setting up issues with mailgun

Tags: dns, mailgun

I am trying to use mailgun. I managed to use it for testing purposes.
But now I would like to set it for good. And I am having a hard time with the details.

My present concern is: ***How do I verify my domain?***

I am following this:
https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202052074-How-do-I-verify-my-domain-

It says "*Open your DNS provider and add the values found in your control panel*."

I think I found something in my DNS provider, but I can't figure out where to add it.
What does "control panel" means here?

Answer (score 0):

By "control panel" they mean your Mailgun's control panel. You will find some values there which you'll have to copy and paste them into your DNS provider's panel.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's a bit clearer. By some value, you mean the one in the column "Enter This Value" I suppose. But where about in my DNS provider's panel do I need to put that?

Comment: It depends on what provider you use. GoDaddy maybe?